# Chess Engine Using Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have decided to start a project over my semester break to create a chess engine using asp.net.  I have a good idea on how I am going to implement the engine itself, my question is what is the best way to draw it to the browser?

I was planning on just using an asp:image control and redrawing the pieces over an image of a chessboard on every mouse down event.  I will have a 2D array of ChessPiece objects that has an abstract draw method for drawing the different pieces, sort of like a 2D tile map.  This will be accomplished using the Drawing class in .NET, but I read on the MSDN website that it is not supported by asp.net.

Basically my question is what is the best way to draw server side images to the client using asp.net.  I haven't done anything like this before, so if you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Cheers, Dave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I would make the interface completely with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  You could easily generate the board using HTML and CSS alone.  Then, you would want to create a CSS "sprite" of all your chess pieces.  A sprite is basically a bunch of images stitched together into a single image (then you create CSS classes with different names that specify portions of the sprite to show at a single time).  So you could create something like `<div class="rook white"></div>` that displayed the white rook from the CSS sprite.  You would then make a `<div></div>` element for each of the pieces and place them into your HTML so that they show up in the approach squares on your chessboard.  Then, you could hook up the mousedown/mouseup events on each piece using JavaScript.  I would probably store the board format in memory in JSON format, and then when the user attempted to move the piece, I would validate the move using JavaScript.  If it were a valid move, I'd show a loading spinner and execute an Ajax request via JavaScript to your ASP.NET code.  I would host the ASP.NET code using WebApi.  Your WebApi controller would accept POST data with the new board state.  It could then compute what move the computer should make and return with the new board state as JSON.  Your JavaScript could then update its internal JSON, and you could have that update the HTML interface.  An easy way to implement two-way binding like this would be to use Angular.js or Knockout.js.  If you used either framework, you could avoid setting up the initial board in HTML and instead setup the board in JSON and have it create the corresponding HTML accordingly.  After the board state was updated, I would hide the loading spinner.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to learn, it might be worth figuring out how to draw this all on the client side using canvas - update some html 5 skills at the same time.  That way you can implement nice drag/drop kind of animations etc...